# In what sense the partial sum in Taylor are equal to the function?

Tags: complex-analysis

If f$(z)$ is an entire function, $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$. This is meaning that $f(z)=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^m a_k z^k$. In what sense should this limit be interpreted? topology of convergence uniform on compact set?

Comment: A priori it's just pointwise-convergence: for each $z$, the associated infinite sum is (= the sequence of partial sums converges to) the value $f(z)$. However we do get some additional uniformity via general properties of analytic functions (see [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_complex_analysis)).

Comment: The definition of $\ell=\lim_{m\to\infty}x_m$ is non-ambiguous, and applies to your $\ell=f(z),x_m=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k z^k,$ which therefore  needs no "interpretation".